# Filter child list and return parent list to view

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list in EF as well as:

[image]

and the child list Social is:
[image]

Now, I want to filter the child list `Socials` and return to view the parent model in these images.

My code is:

```
  var viewModel = await _socialService.GetPagedListAsyncResultSearch(new 

SocialSearchRequestResultSearch(), new List<string>());
            // بعد از آمدن از فیلتر در سمت سرچ
```

I want filter this list:

```
       viewModel.Socials.Select(e => e.InstitudeId == ins.Id).ToList();
```

My code is wrong.

help me.

Comment: What part of you code is wrong? How is it wrong? Do you get an error? And what are those screenshots?

Comment: `viewModel.Socials.Select(e => e.InstitudeId == User.Institude.Id).ToList();` not filtered list `Socials`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var viewModel = await _socialService.GetPagedListAsyncResultSearch(new SocialSearchRequestResultSearch(), new List<string>());
viewModel.Socials.RemoveAll(e => e.InstitudeId != ins.Id);
```

Comment: In my project `RemoveAll` is unknown.

Comment: @MojtabaNava Add System.Collections.Generic namespace

Comment: I added it to my top controller.
`RemoveAll` is unknown in `IEnumerable` type list.

Comment: @MojtabaNava Aha then the easiest fix is to change that type to List. You cannot alter an IEnumerable type unless you replace it with a new one.